# Connection between isometries and projectors in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, unitarity

I realize this question is technically a mathematical one but I think it is seen often enough in quantum information so I ask it here. The following is the definition of an isometry in Mark Wilde's book

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{H}^{\prime}$ be Hilbert spaces such
>   that $\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal{H}) \leq$
>   $\operatorname{dim}\left(\mathcal{H}^{\prime}\right)$ An isometry $V$
>   is a linear map from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}^{\prime}$ such that
>   $V^{\dagger} V=I_{\mathcal{H}}$. Equivalently, an isometry $V$ is a
>   linear, norm-preserving operator, in the sense that
>   $\||\psi\rangle\left\|_{2}=\right\| V|\psi\rangle \|_{2}$ for all
>   $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$.

He also points out that $V V^{\dagger}=\Pi_{\mathcal{H}^{\prime}}$ which is a projection onto $\mathcal{H'}$.

My questions are about $V^\dagger$.

1. By the definition, it is not an isometry but it is a linear map from $\mathcal{H'}$ to $\mathcal{H}$. Is $V^\dagger$ itself a projector from $\mathcal{H'}$ to a subspace of $\mathcal{H'}$ of dimension $\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})$ followed by a unitary from this subspace to $\mathcal{H}$?
2. Does every projector have a corresponding isometry? That is, suppose I am given a projector $\Pi_{\mathcal{H}}$ onto a subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ called $\mathcal{K}$. Then does every isometry $V$ from $\mathcal{K}$ to $\mathcal{H}$ satisfy $VV^\dagger = \Pi_{\mathcal{H}}$?

Comment: "What is it" is not a well-defined question.  Also, what do you mean by "construct an isometry from a projector" -- what condition should it satisfy?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, thanks for the feedback. I have edited and hopefully the question is clearer now.

Comment: I think the best way to think about isometries (as a physicists and in finite dimensions) is as a number of columns taken from a unitary.  (So if V are columns of a unitary, then $V^\dagger$ are some rows of a unitary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can characterise isometries as those linear maps that can be written in the form
$$V = \sum_{k=1}^d |u_k'\rangle\!\langle u_k| \in \operatorname{Lin}(\mathcal H,\mathcal H'),$$
where $\{|u_k\rangle\}_k$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal H$, $\{|u_k'\rangle\}_k$ is an orthonormal set in $\mathcal H'$ (but not a basis if $\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal H)<\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal H')$), and $d\equiv\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal H)$.

In this notation, $V^\dagger$ is obtained by simply switching $|u_k\rangle$ and $|u_k'\rangle$:
$$V^\dagger = \sum_{k=1}^d |u_k\rangle\!\langle u_k'| \in \operatorname{Lin}(\mathcal H',\mathcal H).$$

Now to address your questions:

1. Indeed, $V^\dagger$ is not an isometry if $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal H<\operatorname{dim}\mathcal H'$. You can write it as
   $$V^\dagger = \left( \sum_{j=1}^d |u_j\rangle\!\langle u_j'| \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^d |u_k'\rangle\!\langle u_k'| \right)=V^\dagger \left( \sum_{k=1}^d |u_k'\rangle\!\langle u_k'| \right).$$
   This amounts to simply multiplying to the right with a projector onto the support of $V^\dagger$, which you can always do freely.
   This clearly is not a very insightful statement.
   However, you could think of $V^\dagger$ as a unitary operation when restricting its domain to its support. In other words, $V^\dagger|_{\operatorname{supp}(V^\dagger)}$ is unitary. That's probably how close you can get to your statement.
2. Let $W:\mathcal K\to\mathcal H$ be an isometry, with $d'\equiv \operatorname{dim}\mathcal K\le d$. Then we can write it as
   $$ W = \sum_{k=1}^{d'} |v_k\rangle\!\langle v_k'|,$$
   with $|v_k'\rangle$ orthonormal basis for $\mathcal K$ and $|v_k\rangle$ orthonormal set in $\mathcal H$. Then,
   $$ W W^\dagger = \sum_{k=1}^{d'} |v_k\rangle\!\langle v_k|.$$
   This is therefore a projector onto a subset of $\mathcal H$ of dimension $d'$ (though not necessarily a projector onto $\mathcal K$).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm sorry if I keep repeating the same question but the aspect that has me confused is that you have also called $V^\dagger$ an isometry. But according to the definition (in my original question), if $\text{dim}(\mathcal{H})<\text{dim}(\mathcal{H'})$, then $V^\dagger$ is not an isometry. Is this correct? According to Wilde's definition, an isometry cannot be a map from a larger to a smaller space.

Comment: @user1936752 good point, that is correct. An explicit example probably makes it easier to understand. Suppose $d=2$. Then $V= |3\rangle\!\langle 0|+|2\rangle\!\langle 1|$ is an isometry. But $V^\dagger=|0\rangle\!\langle3|+|1\rangle\!\langle 2|$ is not an isometry. E.g. it doesn't preserve the norm of $|1\rangle\in\mathcal H'$. Although I think one could argue that it is an isometry (and unitary) as a map between its support and its range.

Answer (score 2):

A partial isometry is mapping a sub-vector space $K$ of a Hilbert space $H$ onto another sub-vector space $K'$ of the same dimension *isometrically*, that is

$$(V\psi, V\phi) = (\psi,\phi)$$

for any two vectors in the initial domain of the isometry, that is $K=V^*VH$. The fact that $V^*VH$ is the initial domain of $V$ can be proved by showing that $E=V^*V$ is precisely the projection onto $K$. Similarly, one can show that $F=VV^*$ is the projection onto $K'$, so that $K' = FH$. To get an idea of what a partial isometry is, observe that every unitary is a partial isometry, but not every partial isometry is a unitary because $V^*VH$ and $VV^*H$ are generally not the whole of $H$ (although they could be isomorphic to it). Indeed, when $K$ is all of $H$, one talks about isometries. An important example of an isometry is the adjoint of the shift operator $S$ on a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ with ONB $\{e_0,e_1,\ldots\}$,

$$Se_0=0,\qquad Se_k=e_{k-1}.$$

Note how $S^*$ maps the whole of $H$ onto the orthogonal complement of $e_0$ *isometrically*.

It is also easy to prove the following identities that characterise partial isometries:

$$VV^*V = V\qquad V^*VV^* = V^*.$$

Finally, one sees that projections are (rather trivial) examples of partial isometries.

Comment: This is *not* what Wikipedia says!  (There, essentially H=K).

Comment: Then Wikipedia needs fixing

Comment: To me, an isometry $V:H\to H'$ maps a vector space $H$ to a subspace of $H'$ (preserving the scalar product), and not only a subspace of $H$.  Differently speaking, it is a number of columns taken from a unitary.  (Note that the OP cites the same definition.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in the definition of Wilde, it says the isometry maps $\mathcal{H}$ to a larger or equally large space $\mathcal{H'}$. But you say it maps to a smaller space?

Comment: Edited the comment above (already a few minutes ago).  Isometry = (isometric) embedding - of the full $H$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't know where you're reading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry

Comment: I am talking about isometries, not *partial* isometries -- just as you do at the beginning of your post.  However, what you define there is right away a *partial* isometry, while you call it an isometry.  (I am reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry#Linear_isometry)

Comment: i generally don't distinguish between the two (as what others call an isometry is just a special case of a partial isometry)

Comment: Given what the OP calls an isometry (and everyone else) and what you call an isometry, this is rather misleading.  Why don't you start your post by saying that you will consider a more general case, namely the one of partial isometries, which includes isometries?  (Ah, I see, you edited.  But I guess it wouldn't hurt to say that they are a more general case.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am still a bit unsure of the specific two questions I asked though? Am I right to think of $V^\dagger$ as a projector followed by a unitary?

Comment: A projection $E$ followed by a unitary $U$ cannot be an isometry because its initial domain won't be the whole of the Hilbert space $H$, but just $EH$.

Comment: Yes, but indeed, $V^\dagger$ is not an isometry (I'm using the definition of Wilde as written in the question). Does it make sense?